# What is the difference between "get it over" and "get over it"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I was wondering if there are grammatical differences between "get it over" and "get over it"?

If "over" is an adverb, "it" as a pronoun must be between "get" and "over", which is what I learned from grammar; so in "get over it", "over" must be a preposition?

Comment: *Get it over* by itself is not grammatical: are you thinking of the expression "get it over with"?

Comment: Can be. Are you sure it is not said?

Comment: @Tim, it can be used without ...with, see the results here - http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Get%20it%20over%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1993,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#sclient=psy&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A1993%2Ccd_max%3A2000%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22Get+it+over%22+-%22get+it+over+with%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b0d8e11a30ccd6f1&biw=1390&bih=807 ; however on its own it is not so common and much more common use is as "get it over with"

Comment: @Unreason Here it has other meaning than *get it over with*. For example, *get it over foot-high obstacles* means *get something past foot-high obstacles over their top*. Although I must admit there is one usage where meaning seems to be the same as *get it over with* - in the abstract from the book (?) Winging It . . . - Page 164

Comment: @Philoto, I do understand that, initial question was can you have just "get it over" (http://books.google.com/books?id=CmtrykCMkgsC&pg=PA177&dq=%22Get+it+over%22+-%22get+it+over+with%22&hl=en&ei=45LvTe-DHIuf-wbB1pmFCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBTha#v=onepage&q=%22Get%20it%20over%22%20-%22get%20it%20over%20with%22&f=false) and I do remember hearing it...

Comment: @Unreason Apparently yes, but you have to read a couple of examples there to find this exact meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several entries for [to get](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/get), in the phrasal verb section, so I thought I'd include them all. I separated them so the message is more comprehensible. Note that the last two are very similar except for the preposition "*get sth over **with***" vs "*get sth over **to** somebody*". All the examples and definitions are mainly taken from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, with a double check on my NOAD (for example, what I wrote between parentheses in "get over sth/sb".

1. **get over something**
   To deal with or gain control of something.

   > "*She can't get over her shyness.*"
2. **get over something/somebody**
   To return to your usual state of health, happiness, etc. after an illness, a shock, the end of a relationship, etc. (Recover or *overcome* a difficulty)

   > "*He was disappointed at not getting the job, but he'll get over it.*"

---

1. **get something over (with)** (informal)
   To complete something unpleasant but necessary.

   > "*I'll be glad to get the exam over and done with.*"
2. **get something <-> over (to somebody)**
   To make something clear to somebody.

   > "*He didn't really get his meaning over to the audience.*"

Answer (score 1):

These are quite different.

*Get over it* means *Don't concern yourself with something that's already in the past; accept it and move on to more productive pursuits* [from this site](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/get-over-it.html). Here *get over* is a verb with modifier preposition (please correct me if I'm wrong here, I'm awful when it comes to theory) and should not be separated by pronoun.

*Get it over with* (edited, thanks phenry) may mean *finish it*, *stop it*.

Comment: Here, *to get over sth* is an example of a *phrasal verb* where the combination of *verb* and *preposition* essentially form a new verb with a different meaning that may have little to do with either particle's intrinsic meaning.